# How do I format a request.get using an XMLHttpRequest example

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request, xmlhttprequest

### Goal

I would like to use the npm package `request` to get data from an API endpoint. The example I am following uses `XMLHttpRequest()` to get the data.

### Question

How do I *convert* the `XMLHttpRequest()` to a `request.get`

### Example Code

The [OnSIP example](https://developer.onsip.com/docs/admin-api/authentication) I am following provides the following:

**cURL example:**

```
curl -X POST \
--data \
'Action=SessionCreate&Username=john.doe%40example.onsip.com&Password=mysuperpassword' \
https://api.onsip.com/api
```

**XMLHttpRequest() example:**

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('Action', 'SessionCreate');
data.append('Username', 'john.doe@example.onsip.com');
data.append('Password', 'mysuperpassword');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.onsip.com/api', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}
xhr.send(data);
```

### What I Tried

**cURL**

When I put my credentials into the `cURL` command, I have success, and the response indicates `<IsValid>true</IsValid>`
.

**node.js**

I took the `cURL` example and used this [cURL to Node.js tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/#node) to get started.

```
// Config Settings
const onsipAction = "SessionCreate";
const onsipEmail = encodeURIComponent(onsipConfig.email);
const onsipPassword = onsipConfig.password;
const dataString = "Action=" + onsipAction +
                    "&Username=" + onsipEmail + 
                    "&Password=" + onsipPassword;

console.log("dataString :", dataString);
const onsipSessionCreateOptions = {
    url: "https://api.onsip.com/api",
    method: "POST",
    body: dataString
};

exports.getOnsipSessionId = function (request){
    return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(onsipSessionCreateOptions, function (err, _resp, body) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
                console.log("body :", body);
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log("err:", err)));
};
```

**Logs**

I see this error in the `body`, but not sure what it means.
`Accessor parameter is required, but none was specified.`

```
datastring: Action=SessionCreate&Username=fakename%40jahnelgroup.onsip.com&Password=fakepass
```

and this is the `body`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response
    xmlns="http://www.jnctn.net/ns/rest/2006-01">
    <Context>
        <Action>
            <IsCompleted>false</IsCompleted>
        </Action>
        <Request>
            <IsValid>false</IsValid>
            <DateTime>2019-02-06T15:18:10+00:00</DateTime>
            <Duration>1</Duration>
            <Errors>
                <Error>
                    <Parameter>Action</Parameter>
                    <Code>Accessor.Required</Code>
                    <Message>Accessor parameter is required, but none was specified.</Message>
                </Error>
            </Errors>
        </Request>
        <Session>
            <IsEstablished>false</IsEstablished>
        </Session>
    </Context>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request appears to be a `POST`, rather than a `GET`.

Try the following snippet to recreate your XMLHttpRequest using Node:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.onsip.com/api',
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data;' },
  formData: 
   { Action: 'SessionCreate',
     Username: 'john.doe@example.onsip.com',
     Password: 'mysuperpassword' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

It's basic (doesn't include email encoding for instance), but should in theory work.

Comment: Adding the formData might be the hint I needed. Trying this now

Comment: Yes! fixed `request.post` and used `formData`. The excellent devs at OnSIP quickly confirmed what Mo A was saying.

Comment: Turns out, the username-encoding was not needed for this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

### The Issue

As Mo A shows in his answer, I missed two things:

- `request.get` is wrong, instead `request.post` is correct.
- The OnSIP endpoint is ready for `formData`

### The code that works for me

```
// Config Settings
const onsipAction = "SessionCreate";
const onsipEmail = onsipConfig.email;
const onsipPassword = onsipConfig.password;
const options = { method: "POST",
    url: "https://api.onsip.com/api",
    headers: 
 { "content-type": "multipart/form-data;" },
    formData:
  { Action: onsipAction,
    Username: onsipEmail,
    Password: onsipPassword,
    Output: "json"
  }
};
exports.getOnsipSessionId = function (request){
    return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.post(options, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
                console.log("body :", body);
                resolve(body); // Contains SessionId
            }
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log("err:", err)));
};
```

Thanks, Mo A, OnSIP Devs, and MShirk for the support!